# Nuget package restore repeatedly adding itself to project file

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package-restore

From reading [this](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore) and other sources on the internet, I understand that Nuget Package Restore should probably be not explicitly set on a solution or on a project.  At some point in the past, this has been enabled on my current solution, but is no longer.

I'm currently struggling with a bazaar behaviour, whereby package restore is NOT enabled, either in my project, or in my solution.  However, when I save my work, or try to check into TFS, VS is trying to add package restore to the project.  Clearly there is a hidden (or at least difficult to find) setting that controls this - could someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 0):

A Nuget solution file contains the following

```
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = ".nuget", ".nuget", "{8F66FD94-E98A-4D8C-A27B-E8B550DA7076}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        .nuget\NuGet.Config = .nuget\NuGet.Config
        .nuget\NuGet.exe = .nuget\NuGet.exe
        .nuget\NuGet.targets = .nuget\NuGet.targets
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

Comment: It turned out to be the VS suo file.

Comment: at least you fixed it :-D